# correct method of finding which TLS versions are supported

Tags: powershell

We'll be disabling TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 on our domain controllers for security reasons. But before we do that, I want to check a list of computers and see which TLS versions they have enabled, to make sure they'll keep authenticating with the domain controllers after the legacy TLS versions are disabled.

I wrote a PowerShell script that loops through the list of computers and runs "Get-TlsCipherSuite", but most of the remote computers don't recognize the command, and I don't want to install it just for this query.

I also run a query on registry "HKLM SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols" as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings?tabs=diffie-hellman) Microsoft article, but the protocols registry key, does not contain any TLS entries

So basically I'm looking for the correct command or query, which Ideally I will loop through all the computers using PowerShell and get which TLS versions are supported.

Comment: Microsoft pushed a security update in June 2020 which disabled SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 on all servers.

Comment: some of the computers we're working with are windows 10iot devices, so I'd be more comfortable checking them anyways. Do you have a reference KB article?

Comment: There were a flood of postings after the change was made an answered a lot of postings.  Found following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/transport-layer-security-1x-disablement?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this can help

```
$cred     = Get-Credential -Message "Please enter your admin credentials"
$machines = 'DC01','DC02','DC03'  # the list of computernames to check

$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machines -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    $supported = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
    # values from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName  = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        SystemDefault = [bool]($supported -eq 0)
        Ssl3          = [bool]($supported -band 48)
        Tls           = [bool]($supported -band 192)
        Tls11         = [bool]($supported -band 768)
        Tls12         = [bool]($supported -band 3072)
        Tls13         = [bool]($supported -band 12288)
    }
}

# remove the extra properties PowerShell
$result = $result | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PS*, RunspaceId
# save to file if you want
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\SecurityProtocols.csv' -NoTypeInformation
# filter out machines supporting Tls1.0 and/or Tls1.1
$result | Where-Object {$_.Tls -eq $true -or $_.Tsl11 -eq $true}

#etc.
```